# SHGetFolderPath

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

This code works for windows 7
but doesn't work for windows XP (outputs only part of startup folder path)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    wchar_t startupFolder[1024];
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_STARTUP, 0, 0, startupFolder);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        wcout << L"Startup folder = " << startupFolder << endl;
    else
        cout << "Error when getting startup folder\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

output is:
Startup folder = C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\ <- cursor is here.
Newline is not provided. 
Also I have russian window xp. I think this is unicode issue.

when I use wprintf I got:
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\???????? .....

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it seems like a Unicode issue. Try to use SHGetFolderPathW and update us what happened

Comment: @Flot2011 I'm using unicode characters. Anyway, I put W, but this doesn't help.

Comment: @Flot2011 startupFolder is `wchar_t[1024]` so clearly `SHGetFolderPathW` is already being called. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the font that your XP console uses does not contain glyphs for the Russian characters you are trying to output. The fonts that Windows 7 ships with and uses by default in its console do have a much broader coverage of Unicode code points. You'll need to configure your console to use a font that contains the glyphs you want.

Comment: Yes there was only problem with console output. Everything else works fine.